# Argo Rollouts - How to abort/rollback canary rollout

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argocd, argo-rollouts

I'm working on a POC for Argo Rollouts and all is good for rolling out an application.
However my rollback testing is a bit confusing.
When I abort the rollout the canary get successfully `ScaledDown`, however the overall rollout status is set to `degraded`.

When I attempt to undo the rollout an error `failed restoring revision 0`

Anyone have an suggestions about what the issue might be or how to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

After aborting a rollout, it's normal to be in `degraded` status. It only means that next step is updating your spec back to the stable version.